# virtualenv not copying the existing python modules

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
python -c 'import pyscopg2'
```

this works fine.

Now I create a virtualenv

```
virtualenv venv
```

and activate it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

and run the following

```
python -c 'import pyscopg2'
```

But it gives error 'ImportError: No module named pyscopg2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create virtual environment using `--system-site-packages` option to access system package.

According to `virtualenv --help`:

```
--no-site-packages    Don't give access to the global site-packages dir to
                      the virtual environment (default)
--system-site-packages
                      Give access to the global site-packages dir to the
                      virtual environment
```

Comment: I just want to copy the '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages' once to my 'venv' during the creation of 'venv'. the documentation [http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-system-site-packages-option] says 'inherit' does that mean copy or create a link. Also after using '--system-site-packages', any packages I install inside 'venv' will remain local right ?